# Port forwarding with URL on OpenBSD 4.5

Tags: port-forwarding, openbsd

I need to setup forwarding on gateway machine with following request from client:
Is it possible to setup pf.conf on OpenBSD 4.5 machine, but instead IP address to have given URL such as http://example.com?

I already done settings of port forwarding with IP address. Here it is:

```
rdr on $ext_if proto tcp from any to $ext_if port 9090 -> 192.168.100.21
```

Above is Redirection section. And in Filter Rules:

```
pass in quick on $ext_if inet proto tcp from any to 192.168.100.21 port 9090
```

This a gateway machine where I only can set port forwarding.

Please, could someone help me - is it possible or not. I read about it, but nowhere found example of souch settings.

Comment: Instead of IP addresses you can put DNS names to pf.conf, too. Those will be resolved once when pf reads its rules. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that was the initial idea. Thank you very much. I will test it

Comment: @JannePikkarainen can you record the answer so the question can be closed? Also note that the DNS lookup only occurs once when the rules are loaded.